# How to calculate mean and standard deviation of a range variable (grades) when the raw data is based on frequency categories?

Tags: self-study, standard-deviation, mean, normality-assumption

Results of an exam indicate that:

- 13% of the class earned an A
- 20% earned a B
- 48% earned a C
- 10% earned a D
- 9% earned F's

The grade C ranges from 70-79%. Assuming that the data is normally distributed, determine the mean and standard deviation of the grades.

I am having the most trouble calculating mean. Once the mean is found I am confident that I can find the standard deviation.

Comment: Because this is a self-study/homework question, you should add the `self-study` tag by editing your question. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: Hints: (1) Focus on the information about the C grades: from it you can determine two percentiles of the distribution. (2) The information is given in a misleading and ambiguous manner. Knowing that fractional grades are extremely rare, we probably should understand the interval from 70 to 79% either as representing all numbers from 69.5 to 79.5 (if grades are rounded) or from 70 to 80 (if grades are truncated). The effects of these assumptions on the mean are obviously small, but the effects on the SD are a little bit greater.

Comment: @whuber I am still having trouble calculating the mean correctly. I have been doing (69.5+79.5)/2 to find the midpoints for each grade, then multiplying that midpoint by the respective whole % (assuming the class consisted of 100 students). Next I add up the totals ((69.5+79.5)/2)48+... and divide by 100, but I have a feeling this is wrong. And sorry I'm not very familiar with percentiles, we've really only worked with the z-table.